# Content Security Policy breaks site with iOS clients

Tags: ios, content-security-policy

I recently started to use CSP headers with an existing site, and it seems to be working fine with most users, but I have now received reports of the site not loading with iOS (Safari and Chrome) and can also confirm that my venerable iPad cannot load the site either.

The "violated-directive" is reported as:

```
"script-src 'self' 'nonce-sh7cn3n6shh36sa1' cdn.jsdelivr.net ..other uris
```

i.e. pretty standard.

I have looked around and found reports of similar problem reports [with iframes](https://www.troyhunt.com/how-to-break-your-site-with-content/) and with [web sockets](https://github.com/thelounge/lounge/issues/580) but my sites don't use either of these, its standard HTML + Javascript.

The CSP in its entirety is:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only "default-src 'self'; \
   script-src 'self' 'nonce-sh7cn3n6shh36sa1' cdn.jsdelivr.net \
              oss.maxcdn.com \
              ajax.googleapis.com \
              cdnjs.cloudflare.com \
              www.google-analytics.com;  \
   style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' \
              cdn.jsdelivr.net \
              cdnjs.cloudflare.com \
              maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com; \
   font-src   'self' maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com; \
   img-src    'self' data: www.google-analytics.com www.paypalobjects.com; \
```

What is best practice here? Is there some way to ensure that the CSP will be compatible with all browsers and OS (like a safe subset?).

I'd like to use it, but obviously it is rather problematic not knowing what can be used. Need a "W3C CSP compatibility test" or similar...

Comment: I'm still seeing this as an issue in iOS Safari on older devices. Not sure about newer ones. MacOS Safari 10 accepts the nonce and works as expected.

Answer (score 6):

That's because your [source expressions](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#source-expression) lack a scheme: Safari requires them.
As for Chrome, as all browsers on iOS*, it's just using a wrapper of Safari's engine.

<sub>* [unless you are European and the version is ≥17.4](https://www.theverge.com/2024/1/25/24050478/apple-ios-17-4-browser-engines-eu)</sub>

Comment: Thanks. I concluded that CSP was effectively unusable for me, lacking the resources to test against every old version of a browser. I found a bunch of other problems when I Googled it.  I did find https://cspvalidator.org/ recently, but it only validates for correctness (my CSP passes), not compatibility.

Comment: Safari seems to be retarded with CSP header, I allowListed the whole domain using *.domain.com but it still refuses to load my js when it's inside an iframe. It can't even print a proper error message but it only prints this cryptic message `Failed to load resource: The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303.)` which I can't find any useful information about on the internet..